AppIntents: EntityPropertyQuery with property from related entity
I am working on creating a "Find Intent" by adopting EntityPropertyQuery for my App Entity. I want the user to be able to use Shortcuts to search by a property in a related entity. I know the documentation for 'EntityPropertyQuery' suggests that this should be possible with a initializer for the 'QueryProperty' that takes in a 'entityProvider' but I can't figure out how the syntax works.
For e.g. my CJPersonAppEntity has 'emails', which is of type CJEmailAppEntity, which has a property 'emailAddress'. I want the user to be able to find the 'person' by searching for the email address.
When I try to provide this as a Property to filter by, inside CJPersonAppEntityQuery, but I get a syntax error:
struct CJPersonAppEntityQuery: EntityPropertyQuery, EntityStringQuery {

        static var properties = QueryProperties {
            
            Property(\CJPersonEmailAppEntity.$emailAddress, entityProvider: { person in
                person.emails // error
            }) {
                EqualToComparator { NSPredicate(format: "emailAddress == %@", $0) }
                ContainsComparator { NSPredicate(format: "emailAddress CONTAINS %@", $0) }
            }
}

The error says "Cannot convert value of type '[CJPersonEmailAppEntity]' to closure result type 'CJPersonEmailAppEntity'"
So it's not expecting an array, but an individual email item. But how do I provide that without running the predicate query that's specified in the closure?
So I tried something like this , just returning something without worrying about correctness:
Property(\CJPersonEmailAppEntity.$emailAddress, entityProvider: { person in
                person.emails.first ?? CJPersonEmailAppEntity() // satisfy compiler
            }) {
                EqualToComparator { NSPredicate(format: "emailAddress == %@", $0) }
                ContainsComparator { NSPredicate(format: "emailAddress CONTAINS %@", $0) }
            }

and it built the app, but failed on another the step:

'Extracting app intents metadata': error: Entity CJPersonAppEntity
does not contain a property named emailAddress. Ensure that the
property is wrapped with an @Property property wrapper

So I'm not sure what the correct syntax for handling this case is, and I can't find any other examples of how it's done. Would love some feedback for this.
This is what the documentation says for EntityQueryProperty:

/// An EntityQueryProperty doesn't necessarily need to apply to a
property of its parent Query /// Entity. /// /// Consider the
scenario where you have an application containing Photo and Album
entities, and you /// want to support querying photos by the name of
their containing album. Within a /// EntityPropertyQuery in which
Entity is Photo, you can define a EntityQueryProperty mapping to
/// a name property of the Album entity, as long as you supply a
closure for entityProvider that /// contains the logic to get from a
Photo entity to an Album entity.

